# Statistics App for multiple sites

Tags: webapp-rec, statistics

I want to provide all my clients with a statistics tracking code and then they can log into MY control panel to view their statistics; ie I need some sort of script where I provide their site ID and their statistics will be embedded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)! I use it all the time! And perfect for your needs!
piwik.org

Comment: This is good because it has copy and paste widget embedding. Thanks!

Comment: True true. plus, it auto-updates. really nifty!

Answer (score 1):

Try with [Google Analytics](http://analytics.google.com)